# Documenting server details

Tags: linux, documentation

This could be a very naive question for many of you, but I have problem in answering this one, your help will be deeply appreciated.

I need to document the server on which I work, and it should include following heads:

1. IP address ->
2. Model-> (Dell....)
3. CPU->(@X Quad-core ....)
4. RAM->(48GB...)
5. Adapter external->(Dell Perc...)
6. Disk local->(6 x 1Tb raid....)
7. Adapter external->(Dell Perc ...)
8. Disk attached->(....)
9. Capacity external disk->(.....)

In brackets, I have put the kind of documentation needed for each head.

Is there any one command (shell/bash) or a group of commands that can be used to get this kind of documentation for my server.

Comment: Is it all specifically Dell kit?

Comment: No, its a HP kit

Comment: Thanks Angelo - in that case you simply want HP Systems Insight Manager - it's free and does everything you've asked for and more including patch/firmware management, alerting all manner of things.

Comment: Hi Chopper3, I am using Linux OS and I need linux/shell/bash commands

Comment: Understood - just saying that if you got HP SIM I think you'd benefit

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick script/collection of commands to get you started. Add commands (ifconfig, lspci, etc.) as you see fit:

```
#!/bin/bash
# hwcollect.sh - Collect general system information

# Hostname
echo -e "$HOSTNAME \n"

# Display system manufacturer, model, serial and other attributes
dmidecode -t 1 | egrep '(Manufacturer|Product|Serial)'
dmidecode -t 3 | egrep '(Height)';
dmidecode  -t processor| egrep '(Socket|Version)'
# Calculate installed RAM
dmidecode -t 17 | awk '( /Size/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) { x+=$2 } END{ print "\t" "Installed Ram: " x "MB"}'

echo " "
echo "Disk Information"
# Filesystem mounts
df -h
# Display disk partition table    
fdisk -l
```

I can run a quick ssh loop or run this individually from a source host using something like: `ssh targethost < hwcollect.sh`

Example:

```
[root@xetra ~]# ssh Test_Server < hwcollect.sh
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Test_Server 

        Manufacturer: HP
        Product Name: ProLiant DL380 G6
        Serial Number: 2UX12345KT      
        Height: 2 U
        Socket Designation: Proc 1
        Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5570 @ 2.93GHz            
        Upgrade: Socket LGA1366
        Socket Designation: Proc 2
        Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5570 @ 2.93GHz            
        Upgrade: Socket LGA1366
        Installed Ram: 32768MB

Disk Information
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2      20G  5.1G   14G  28% /
/dev/cciss/c0d0p7     3.0G   74M  2.7G   3% /tmp
/dev/cciss/c0d0p6     5.9G  2.3G  3.3G  42% /var
/dev/cciss/c0d0p3     9.7G  4.7G  4.6G  51% /usr
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1      99M   39M   55M  42% /boot
/dev/cciss/c0d0p8     573G  433G  140G  76% /scratch
/dev/cciss/c0d0p9     1.1T  702G  348G  67% /data
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             400G  298G  103G  75% /data/datatest

Disk /dev/cciss/c0d0: 1800.2 GB, 1800280694784 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 218871 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2              14        2624    20972857+  83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p3            2625        3929    10482412+  83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p4            3930      218871  1726521615    5  Extended
/dev/cciss/c0d0p5            3930        6018    16779861   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/cciss/c0d0p6            6019        6801     6289416   83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p7            6802        7193     3148708+  83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p8            7194       81891   600011653+  83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p9           81892      218871  1100291818+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 429.4 GB, 429496729600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 52216 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1       52216   419424988+  83  Linux
```

Answer (score 4):

Facter, used in Puppet, will collect most of that information for you out of the box. It is fairly easy to add whatever other "facts" you want to collect to it.

- https://puppetlabs.com/blog/facter-part-1-facter-101/
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/facter.html
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/custom_facts.html

Comment: But it means installing Puppet :(

Comment: ...which may not be a bad thing :-)

Answer (score 2):

bunch of commands to get you started.

dmidecode

df -h

lscpu

free -g

lspci

lsusb

ip addr

uname -a

Answer (score 1):

**lshw** is the command you looking for.

Comment: oddly, that was in my original answer but i couldn't get it to work, so i figured i must have dreamt it up. It works now, lol.

Answer (score 1):

[dmesg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) (aka Driver Message) will give you all this information, and far more besides.

Edit: Actually, it won't give you the IP address, but `ifconfig` will give you that.

Answer (score 0):

We run ocs-ng for our Windows7 client management and „aptitude install ocsinventory-agent“ installs the debian/Linux agent. Also dmidecode is used for hardware inventory .