# Bash loop to move directories on a remote host via ssh

Tags: ssh, bash, remote, host

I'm trying to figure out a way to perform the following loop on a remote host via ssh.

Basically it renames a series of directories to create a rotating backup. But it's local. I want it to work against directories on a remote host.

```
while [ $n -gt 0 ];
    do {
    src=$(($n-1))
    dst=$n
    if [ -d /backup/$src ];
    then {
    mv /backup/$src /backup/$dst;
    }
    fi;
    }
    ((n--))
done;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using bash, you'll want to use `[[` and `]]` instead of `[` and `]`.  It makes it much easier to do comparisons like you're doing here.

First, what is `$n`'s starting value?

Try this:

```
ssh usr@host 'for n in {10..1}; do [[ -d /backup/$(($n-1)) ]] && /bin/mv /backup/$(($n-1)) /backup/${n}; done'
```

That right there should do it.  That's assuming your starting number is `10`.  Depending on where $n is coming from, that can be modified.  Notice that `mv` has the full path specified...  this is because when you execute a remote session in ssh, it tends not to execute your .bashrc and .bash_profile meaning you don't have a ${PATH} yet set.  There might be a way around it, but I don't know what it is.

Written out more human-readably:

```
for n in {10..1}
do
  if [[ -d /backup/$src ]]
  then
    /bin/mv /backup/$src /backup/$dst
  fi
fi
```

Since you're executing it remotely, I figured it would be easier in a single line.

Comment: This is in line with what I'm trying but, I get `syntax error near unexpected token `do'`

Comment: I screwed it up, I apologize.  Swap the " with '

Comment: Look at the current version.  I tested it on my side (with commands other than `mv`) and this works perfectly on my side.  Notice I removed /bin/bash

Answer (score 2):

Place the script in a file on your local machine, e.g. `backup.sh` and run the remote execution like this:

`ssh user@remotehost < backup.sh`

This allows you to run the script on the remote host without actually copying it to the remote host.

I use this method for [gathering hardware specifications from remote systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/365238/documenting-server-details/365298#365298).

Comment: Thanks. This could work, but I am trying to keep it all in one script rather than scripts calling scripts.

Comment: Encapsulating this in a file will be the most maintainable and human-readable/modular approach.

Comment: You can do `ssh user@host <<EOF [enter]your commands[enter]EOF` to keep the script in line.

Comment: I agree that this should have worked. But, there are all sorts of interpreter and piping issues. Thanks anyway