# Get full physical Ram memory with bash

Tags: centos, ssh, bash, memory

I know some of you might find my question stupid but i need to know how much ram is installed on a centos box 
Yes i know it can easily be done by using the command

> awk '/MemTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo

However the problem is that the memory shown is not really want i need.The value shown will always be less than expected as some ram is used to load the kernel.Thus a 512 MB ram server will always show a little less than 524288 kb.

The reason while i need the full physical ram is very simple.I need to modify settings automatically on a box via my bash script. Thus if server has total 512 MB ram , one set of setting is used , if 1gb then another.....

I cannot gamble with the value return by the command above as value varies from system to system.

Any good valid option guys.......

Kind Regards

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: I know comparison with bash ...question is not about bash command here.I need an ssh commmand that can get me the true physical ram installed on server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go... From my larger script at: [Documenting server details](https://serverfault.com/questions/365238/documenting-server-details/365298#365298)

```
# Calculate installed RAM
dmidecode -t 17 | awk '( /Size/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) { x+=$2 } END{ print "\t" "Installed Ram: " x "MB"}'
```

Output: **Installed Ram: 28672MB** (or divide by 1024)

Comment: Thanks so much.However i need to installed dmidecode then...i though it could be without any 3rd party.Dude can you modify the command so that it output only 28672 and not "Installed Ram:" and MB(its for convenience....

Comment: I haven't learn awk yet , i know only sed for now....regards ewwhite

Comment: @Werulz `dmidecode -t 17 | awk '( /Size/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) { x+=$2 } END{ print x }'`

Comment: Bro i have a little question about your command.It may happen that dmidecode contain Size multiple times like in http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/how-to-get-hardware-information-on-linux-using-dmidecode-command/ .Do the command automatically add all values of "Size"....Thanks

Comment: @Werulz Yes. That's what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, dmidecore requires root privileges.

Another way to retrieve values, more accurate than MemTotal in /proc/meminfo :

```
$ dmesg | gawk '/BIOS-e820/&&/usable/{tot+=strtonum("0x"$4)-strtonum("0x"$2)}END{print "Total RAM: "tot/1048576" MB"}'
```